# WMS with additional parameter in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms

In my database I have table which contains data for many users (identifying by USER_ID attribute) and I am looking for a way to filter data in my WMS service by this attribute.
For example request as below:

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/my_location/wms?
    service=WMS
    &version=1.1.0
    &request=GetMap
    &layers=my_location:my_location_history
    &styles=
    &bbox=54.406021,18.531216,54.497708,18.577851
    &width=768
    &height=390
    &srs=EPSG:4326
    &format=application/openlayers
    &user_id = 1
```

should return only data where in my tabele USER_ID = 1.

Currently, for this purpose, I am using ELEVATION dimension. If you have better and/or "more professional" solution, let me know ;)

Comment: Use CQL_FILTER http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html.  Demo request: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME%3D%27Colorado%27&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=769&HEIGHT=331&BBOX=-118.32275390625%2C28.01513671875%2C-84.52880859375%2C42.56103515625 which makes a selection `STATE_NAME='Colorado'`. You should add  `&CQL_FILTER=user_id=1` into your GetMap.